# How can I see safari extension loader logs

Tags: safari, safari-extension

is there a way that I can see complete verbose to what is happening and what does safari in the steps of loading an extension?

I have a problem with how safari loads extensions and I want to see every step of that. Does anyone know if this logs exist and can be viewed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logs can be found inside the Console.app from macOS.